# Passenger: mod_rewrite rules for non-default page cache directory for Rails application

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

Does anybody have some working Apache mod_rewrite rules that enable Phusion Passenger (mod_rails) to use a non-default location for the page cache within a Rails application? I'd like the cached files to go in `/public/cache` rather than the default of `/public`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [this blog post](http://termos.vemod.net/page-caching-with-rails-and-passenger):

```
RailsAllowModRewrite On  
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^.]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^/[^.]+$ /cache/%1.html [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/$ /cache/index.html [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer with RailsAllowModRewrite does not works, as in new versions RailsAllowModRewrite does nothing, but the passenger interaction with mod_rewrite seems to be broken.